# How to bootstrap the result of arithmetic operation of regression coefficients of two models

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I want to do bootstrap of the division of the outputs of two regression models to get confidence intervals of the mean of the result of the operation.

**#creating sample data**

```
ldose <- rep(0:5, 2)
numdead <- c(1, 4, 9, 13, 18, 20, 0, 2, 6, 10, 12, 16)
sex <- factor(rep(c("M", "F"), c(6, 6)))
SF <- cbind(numdead, numalive = 20-numdead)
dat<-data.frame(ldose, numdead, sex, SF)
tibble::rowid_to_column(dat, "indices")
```

**#creating the function to be bootstrapped**

```
out<-function(dat) {
     d<-data[indices, ] #allows boot to select sample
     fit1<- glm(SF ~ sex*ldose, family = binomial (link = log), start=c(-1,0,0,0))
     fit2<- glm(SF ~ sex*ldose, family = binomial (link = log), start=c(-1,0,0,0))
     coef1<-coef(fit1)
     numer<-exp(coef1[2])
     coef2<-coef(fit2)
     denom<-exp(coef2[2])
     resultX<-numer/denom
     return(mean(resultX))
}
```

**#doing bootstrap**

```
results <- boot(dat, out, 1000)
```

**#error message**

> Error in statistic(data, original, ...) : unused argument (original)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `out<-function(data, indices) { ...` There are many warnings from `glm` and both models are identical.

Comment: Thanks, @Roland. Yes - the models are identical just for simplicity. Let me test your answer.

Comment: You should also study `help("boot")` where the necessary parameters of the function passed to `statistic` are described.

Comment: Yes. I am doing that. Thanks for the answer. It works but does not give any `se`, even when the models are different. Any thoughts?                                                           
  `#creating the function to be bootstrapped out<-function(data, indices) {...
     fit1<- glm(SF ~ sex*ldose, family = binomial (link = log), start=c(-1,0,0,0))
     fit2<- glm(SF ~ sex + numdead + ldose, family = binomial (link = log), start=c(-1, 0, 0,0)) ...
}#doing bootstrap results <- boot::boot(dat, out, 1000)`

Comment: Maybe you should test with models that converge without problems. Look at `results$t`. Those are the bootstrap samples.

Comment: Thanks @Roland. I will keep exploring.

Comment: I don't see `d` being passed to `glm()`.  It should be the `data` argument.

Comment: Yes, it works without passing `d`. Otherwise, why would this work? Try this after running the function: `glm(SF ~ sex*ldose, family = binomial (link = log), start=c(-1,0,0,0)`.

Comment: I think that is not behind my problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you should use the `data` argument in `glm`. It's using the variables from the global environment otherwise and that's the reason you get identical bootstrap estimates.

Comment: Yes. You are both right. Indeed after passing `d`I can get the `se`. Thank you for your insight.